# WAS getting changed to 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-rad

I Installed Webspehere Application Server 8.5 on my RAD(Rational Application Developer). While creating I set it to Java 1.7 . After creation its getting changed to Java 1.6.

Please help.

Comment: add more details like where it is getting changed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the instructions on switching WebSphere 8.5.5 from Java 1.6 to Java 1.7:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWLGF_8.5.0/com.ibm.sr.doc/twsr_java17.html

Basically, install Java 7 through Installation Manager and run managesdk:
`For UNIX or Linux, run WAS_HOME/bin/managesdk.sh -enableProfile -profileName profilename -sdkname 1.7_64`
`For Windows, run WAS_HOME/bin/managesdk.bat -enableProfile -profileName profilename -sdkname 1.7_64`